# Sort files into sub folders by date - bash

Tags: bash, sorting, command-line, directory, command

Basically my HDD crashed, I was able to recover all the files, but, all the files have retained their meta & some have retained their names, I have 274000 images, which I need to more or less, sort into folders by date.

So let's say it starts with the first files, it would get the date from the file, create a sub folder, and until the date changes, keep moving that file into the created folder, once the date changes, it would create a new folder and keep doing the same thing.

I'm sure this is possible, I really didn't want to have to do this manually as it would take weeks...

Lets say I have a target folder /target/

Target contains, 274000 files, in no sub folders at all.

The folders structure should be **/target/YY/DD_MM/filenames**

I would like to create a bash script for this, but I'm not really sure where to proceed from here.

I've found this:

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR=/home/data
target=$DIR
cd "$DIR"

for file in *; do

    dname="$( date -d "${file%-*}" "+$target/%Y/%b_%m" )"
    mkdir -vp "${dname%/*}"
    mv -vt "$dname" "$file"

done
```

Would creating a folder without checking if it exists delete files inside that folder?

I'm also not quite sure what adding an asterix to the dir pathname would do?

I'm not quite familiar with bash, but I'd love to get this working if someone could please explain to me a little more what's going on?

Thankyou!

Comment: Are the files contain the date in their names ? Give us a sample input files names

Comment: Not all no, I was hoping there would be a way to get the date from the file it self @sputnick

Comment: Is `ls -ltr` displays different dates for the files ?

Comment: creation date are usually not encoded on files in linux. you can get access date and modified date of a file. Which one of these dates you prefer to sort by?

Comment: @Xorg I have just posted an answer on this thread, would you mind just checking it to make sure I've not made any errors?

Comment: my apologies @Shannon Hochkins

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I seemed to have found an answer that suited me, this worked on OSX just fine on three files, before I run it on the massive folder, can you guys just check that this isn't going to fail somewhere?

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR=/Users/limeworks/Downloads/target
target=$DIR
cd "$DIR"

for file in *; do
    # Top tear folder name
    year=$(stat -f "%Sm" -t "%Y" $file)
    # Secondary folder name
    subfolderName=$(stat -f "%Sm" -t "%d-%m-%Y" $file)

    if [ ! -d "$target/$year" ]; then
        mkdir "$target/$year"
        echo "starting new year: $year"
    fi
    if [ ! -d "$target/$year/$subfolderName" ]; then
        mkdir "$target/$year/$subfolderName"
        echo "starting new day & month folder: $subfolderName"
    fi
    echo "moving file $file"
    mv "$file" "$target/$year/$subfolderName"

done
```

Comment: I have noticed "stat -f "%Sm" -t "%d-%m-%Y" $file" is not outputing the in a human readable fashion..I am getting samples like "32ac003f03444607 255 ef53 4096 4096 16788382 12900871 12042299 4276224 39" for each file. Is this ok?

Comment: Are you using OSX? For me it's not doing it :/

Comment: @ShannonHochkins : What did you end up using?

Comment: Comment by [Matt Danihy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8605279/matt-danihy) in this [non answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46205331/5292302), *answer works great, but it has a problem with filenames with spaces. Without a space it sorts just fine, with space it dumps everything into the root of the target folder*

Comment: matt - in my OP i don't need or have any spaces in file paths, that logic can be extended for you and has no relevance to this OP

Comment: if the file name contains space, this would run into trouble. so replace 
$file 
with 
"$(echo $file)"

Answer (score 4):

I've had issues with the performance of the other solutions since my filesystem is remotely mounted and access times are big.

I've worked on some improved solutions in bash and python:

---

Bash version:

```
record # cat test.sh
for each in *.mkv
do
  date=$(date +%Y-%d-%m -r "$each");
  _DATES+=($date);
  FILES+=($each);
done

DATES=$(printf "%s\n" "${_DATES[@]}" | sort -u);
for date in ${DATES[@]}; do
  if [ ! -d "$date" ]; then
    mkdir "$date"
  fi
done

for i in  ${FILES[@]}; do
  dest=$(date +%Y-%d-%m -r "$i")
  mv $i $dest/$i
done

record # time bash test.sh
real    0m3.785s
record #
```

---

[Python version](https://github.com/grizmin/sortfiles):

```
import os, datetime, errno, argparse, sys

def create_file_list(CWD):
    """ takes string as path, returns tuple(files,date) """

    files_with_mtime = []
    for filename in [f for f in os.listdir(CWD) if os.path.splitext(f)[1] in ext]:
        files_with_mtime.append((filename,datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.stat(filename).st_mtime).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')))
    return files_with_mtime

def create_directories(files):
    """ takes tuple(file,date) from create_file_list() """

    m = []
    for i in files:
        m.append(i[1])
    for i in set(m):
        try:
            os.makedirs(os.path.join(CWD,i))
        except OSError as exception:
            if exception.errno != errno.EEXIST:
                raise

def move_files_to_folders(files):
    """ gets tuple(file,date) from create_file_list() """
    for i in files:
        try:
            os.rename(os.path.join(CWD,i[0]), os.path.join(CWD,(i[1] + '/' + i[0])))
        except Exception as e:
            raise
    return len(files)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog=sys.argv[0], usage='%(prog)s [options]')
    parser.add_argument("-e","--extension",action='append',help="File extensions to match",required=True)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    ext =  ['.' + e for e in args.extension]
    print "Moving files with extensions:", ext
    CWD = os.getcwd()
    files = create_file_list(CWD)
    create_directories(files)
    print "Moved %i files" % move_files_to_folders(files)

record # time python sort.py -e mkv
Moving files with extensions: ['.mkv']
Moved 319 files
real    0m1.543s
record #
```

Both scripts are tested upon 319 mkv files modified in the last 3 days.

Comment: I just tried the python solution on a folder of 80000 jpg files. It worked perfectly and only took 11s.

Comment: Well, this is truly maddening. I just used this yesterday and the python one worked perfectly, I used it a bunch of times and it did what I needed. Today, with nothing at all having changed except I was away from my computer for about 18 hours, `/usr/bin/python: can't find '__main__' module`. Very spooky. The BASH one never worked, there's some syntax error in the Date command that I couldn't figure out.

Answer (score 1):

I worked on a little script and tested it.Hope this helps.

```
#!/bin/bash
pwd=`pwd`
#list all files,cut date, remove duplicate, already sorted by ls.
dates=`ls  -l --time-style=long-iso|grep -e  '^-.*'|awk '{print $6}'|uniq`
#for loop to find all files modified on each unique date and copy them to your pwd
for date in $dates; do
    if [ ! -d "$date" ]; then
        mkdir "$date"
    fi
#find command will find all files modified  at particular dates and ignore hidden files.
    forward_date=`date -d  "$date + 1 day" +%F`
    find "$pwd" -maxdepth 1 -not -path '*/\.*' -type f  -newermt "$date" ! -newermt "$forward_date" -exec cp -f {} "$pwd/$date" \;
done
```

You must be in your working directory where your files to be copied according to date are present.

Comment: What os are you using?