# Python: Can't find '__main__' module in

Tags: python

I've got this python code where I would like to run from Windows Run. However, the cmd displays this message when I try an run it.

`C:\Users\myName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe: can't find '__main__' module in 'C:\\Users\\myName\\OneDrive'`

I am using VS Code to write my program with a python 3.8.3 32-bit virtual enviroment.
The python program is called pw.py and the batch file is called pw.bat

**pw.py**

C:\Users\myName\OneDrive - companyName\04 Programming\01 Visual Studio Code\LearningPython\pw.py

```
#! python3
# pw.py - An insecure password locker program.

import sys, pyperclip

PASSWORD = {'email': 'F7minlBDDuvMJuxESSKHFhTxFtjVB6',
            'blog': 'VmAlvQyKAxiVH5G8vo1if1MLZF3sdt',
            'luggage': '12345'}

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print('Usage: python pw.py [account] - copy account password')
    sys.exit()

account = sys.argv[1]   # first commmand line arg is the account name

if account in PASSWORD:
    pyperclip.copy(PASSWORD[account])
    print('Password for ' + account + ' copied to clipboard.')
else:
    print('There is no account named ' + account)
```

**pw.bat**

C:\Users\myName\MyPythonScripts

```
@py.exe C:\Users\myName\OneDrive - companyName\04 Programming\01 Visual Studio Code\LearningPython\pw.py %*
@pause
```

Comment: In the .bat file the file name + path needs to be in quotes as it has spaces in it

Comment: Yes, if you look closely at the error message you can see where it tried to find your file. `'C:\\Users\\myName\\OneDrive`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, check whether you handle spaces correctly, it's not that obvious. Try to prefix spaces ( ) with backslash (`\` ) in your batch file like that:

```
@py.exe C:\Users\myName\OneDrive\ -\ companyName\04\ Programming\01\ Visual\ Studio\ Code\LearningPython\pw.py %*
@pause
```

Another way to do that is to enclose the path in quotation marks, i.e.:

```
@py.exe "C:\Users\myName\OneDrive - companyName\04 Programming\01 Visual Studio Code\LearningPython\pw.py" %*
@pause
```

---

Also you can consider to add the following:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    #code here
```

after you use `PASSWORDS` dict, i.e.:

```py
#! python3
# pw.py - An insecure password locker program.

import sys, pyperclip

PASSWORD = {'email': 'F7minlBDDuvMJuxESSKHFhTxFtjVB6',
            'blog': 'VmAlvQyKAxiVH5G8vo1if1MLZF3sdt',
            'luggage': '12345'}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print('Usage: python pw.py [account] - copy account password')
        sys.exit()

    # And so on...
```

You can read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do?rq=1) or [there](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html?highlight=__main__#module-__main__)

Comment: this is seriously under-upvoted IMO. anyone care to pay this answer some homage? it was literally "0" when I came to this page, which is unacceptable for the powerful use-cases loaded up in this answer. Of course feel free to disagree, but if you don't, pay some homage please! IMO, stellar answer good sir!

Comment: I kicked it up one as it is valid.  I was looking at a different issue as I am new to pyCharm.  Apparently this appears it I run the project with the green arrow in the upper right corner.  OTOH, if I highlight the line 'if __name__ == "__main__":', and right click and run that way, I don't see the error.

Comment: No homage from me for this apparently incorrect answer. I have spaces backslashed and `if name == "main":` in the script, and still getting `Can't find '__main__' module in` error. In fact, the script worked perfectly fine yesterday and didn't give this error, and I haven't changed anything. It's the script from the second answer here, copied verbatim, and as I said 100% working yesterday, so the issue is something else: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27475057/sort-files-into-sub-folders-by-date-bash